# How can I return NULL from a generic method in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method with this (dummy) code (yes I'm aware IList has predicates, but my code is not using IList but some other collection, anyway this is irrelevant for the question...)

```cs
    static T FindThing<T>(IList collection, int id) where T : IThing, new()
    {
        foreach (T thing in collection)
        {
            if (thing.Id == id)
                return thing;
        }
        return null;  // ERROR: Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead.
    }
```

This gives me a build error

> "Cannot convert null to type parameter
> 'T' because it could be a value type.
> Consider using 'default(T)' instead."

Can I avoid this error?

Comment: Would nullable reference types (in C# 8) be the better solution to this now? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references Returning `null` regardless of whether `T` is `Object` or `int` or `char`.

Comment: Too bad that `T?` in the signature doesn't work. @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I've read the article but couldn't see a way to return `null` regardless of reference or value type.

Comment: @mireazma That's way too little information for me to be able to help. You should open a new question.

Comment: The main problem I see is that you try to use `null` as indication that something is wrong there. I would propose to throw an exception instead. That's why exceptions exist and you can ommit wirting `if (... != null)` everywhere.

Answer (score 1150, accepted):

Three options:

- Return `default` (or `default(T)` for older versions of C#)  which means you'll return `null` if `T` is a reference type (or a nullable value type), `0` for `int`, `'\0'` for `char`, etc. ([Default values table (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table))
- If you're happy to restrict `T` to be a reference type with the `where T : class` constraint and then return `null` as normal
- If you're happy to restrict `T` to be a non-nullable value type with the `where T : struct` constraint, then again you can return `null` as normal from a method with a return value of `T?` - note that this is *not* returning a null reference, but the null value of the nullable value type.

Comment: What if my return type is an enum not a class?  I can't specify T : enum :(

Comment: In .NET an enum is a very thin (and rather leaky) wrapper around an integer type.  The convention is to use zero for your "default" enum value.

Comment: I think the problem with this is that if you're using this generic method to say, convert a Database object from DbNull to Int and it returns default(T) where T is an int, it'll return 0. If this number is actually meaningful, then you'd be passing around bad data in cases where that field was null. Or a better example would be a DateTime. If the field was something like "DateClosed" and it was returned as null because and account is still open, it would actually default(DateTime) to 1/1/0000, implying that the account was closed before computers were invented.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: So you'd convert to `Nullable<int>` or `Nullable<DateTime>` instead. If you use a non-nullable type and need to represent a null value, you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to bring it up. I think what I've been doing is more like MyMethod<T>(); to assume it is a non nullable type and MyMethod<T?>(); to assume it is a nullable type. So in my scenarios, I could use a temp variable to catch a null and go from there.

Comment: Since C# 7.1 (August 2017) you can simplify the syntax of option 1 a bit, into `return default;`, because the type is automatically inferred.

Answer (score 112):

```
return default(T);
```

Comment: This link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(VS.80).aspx 

should explain why.

Comment: Damn it, I would've saved a lot of time had I known about this keyword - thanks Ricardo!

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't gotten more up votes as the 'default' keyword is a more comprehensive solution, allowing the use of non-reference types in conjunction with numeric types and structs. While the accepted answer solves the problem (and indeed is helpful), it better answers how to restrict return type to nullable/reference types.

Answer (score 49):

You can just adjust your constraints:

```
where T : class
```

Then returning null is allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot choose 2 answers as the accepted solution, so I choose John Skeet's cause his answer has two solutions.

Comment: @Migol it depends on your requirements. Maybe their project does require it be `IDisposable`. Yes, most of the time it doesn't have to be. `System.String` doesn't implement `IDisposable`, for example. The answerer should have clarified that, but that doesn't make the answer wrong. :)

Comment: @Migol I have no clue why I had IDisposable in there.  Removed.

Answer (score 17):

Below are the two option you can use

```
return default(T);
```

or

```
where T : class, IThing
 return null;
```

Answer (score 15):

Add the class constraint as the first constraint to your generic type.

```
static T FindThing<T>(IList collection, int id) where T : class, IThing, new()
```

Comment: Thanks. I cannot choose 2 answers as the accepted solution, so I choose John Skeet's cause his answer has two solutions.

Answer (score 15):

1. If you have object then need to typecast

   ```
   return (T)(object)(employee);
   ```
2. if you need to return null.

   ```
   return default(T);
   ```

Comment: Hi user725388, please verify the first option

Answer (score 8):

Your other option would be to to add this to the end of your declaration:

```
    where T : class
    where T: IList
```

That way it will allow you to return null.

Comment: If both constraints are to the same type, you mention the type once and use a comma, like `where T : class, IList`. If you have constraints to different types, you repeat the token `where`, as in `where TFoo : class where TBar : IList`.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness sake, it's good to know you could also do this:

```
return default;
```

It returns the same as `return default(T);`

Answer (score 5):

solution of TheSoftwareJedi works,

also you can archive it with using couple of value and nullable types:

```
static T? FindThing<T>(IList collection, int id) where T : struct, IThing
{
    foreach T thing in collecion
    {
        if (thing.Id == id)
            return thing;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take the recommendation of the error... and either user `default(T)` or `new T`.

You will have to add in a comparison in your code to ensure that it was a valid match if you go that route.

Otherwise, potentially consider an output parameter for "match found".

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working example for Nullable Enum return values:

```
public static TEnum? ParseOptional<TEnum>(this string value) where TEnum : struct
{
    return value == null ? (TEnum?)null : (TEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), value);
}
```

Comment: Since C# 7.3 (May 2018), you can improve the constraint to `where TEnum : struct, Enum`. This ensures that a caller does not accidentally supply a value type that is not an enum (such as an `int` or a `DateTime`).

Answer (score 3):

Because of IThing is interface is not possible to use null. So you have to use default(T) to determine default value for actual type T which is defined before function is called.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        
        IThing x = new List<Thing>().FindThing(1);
        
    }

}

public static class Ext {
    public static T FindThing<T>(this IList<T> collection, int id) where T : IThing, new()
    {
        foreach (T thing in collection)
        {
            if (thing.Id == id) return (T)thing;
        }
    
        //return null; //not work
        //return (T)null; //not work
        //return null as T; //not work
        return default(T); //work
    }
}

public interface IThing { int Id {get; set;} }
public class Thing : IThing { public int Id {get;set;}}
```

Comment: Did you try this code? Only `return default(T);` will work.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo nope it work. Try it on fiddle.

Comment: Okay, I didn't notice in your answer that your `IThing` is the class so your method knows that `T` is the class, but I'm sure that the author of the question means that `IThing` is an interface (what the `I` prefix is saying about) .

Comment: @E.Shcherbo I have to apologize. You have right. Unfortunately question is not very verbose. Therefore for lazy people as me is not very feasible to achieve same conditions. :D

Comment: no worries, despite the fact that your answer was about other concept (class vs interface) I still think that it was good. It showed the important point how the behaviour of a generic method differs when a type argument is known to be a class or an interface and also emphasised the fact that `where T : IThing`  is also fine with value types.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to 2 answers presented above. If you change your return type to `object`, you can return `null`, while at the same time cast the non-null return.

```
static object FindThing<T>(IList collection, int id)
{
    foreach T thing in collecion
    {
        if (thing.Id == id)
            return (T) thing;
    }
    return null;  // allowed now
}
```

Comment: Downside: this would require the caller of the method to cast the returned object (in non-null case), which implies boxing -> less performance. Am I right?