# C# Is it possible to pass a type into a method and have the method return an object of that type?

Tags: c#

This seems like it would be possible.

```
protected SameObjectTypeAsInputParameterObjectType GetAValue(someObject,TypeOrReturnObjectYouWant){

//check to see if someObject is null, if not, cast it and send the cast back

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your given example you are probably better served just doing the following:

```
MyClass val = myObject as MyClass;
```

However to answer your question - yes, the answer is to use generics:

```
protected T GetAValue<T>(object someObject)
{
    if (someObject is T)
    {
        return (T)someObject;
    }
    else
    {
        // We cannot return null as T may not be nullable
        // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302096/how-can-i-return-null-from-a-generic-method-in-c
        return default(T); 
    }
}
```

In this method T is a **type parameter**.  You can use T in your code in exactly the same way that you would any other type (for example a string), however note that in this case we haven't placed any restriction on what T is, and so objects of type T only have the properties and methods of the base `object` (`GetType()`, `ToString()` etc...)

We must obviously declare what T is before we can use it - for example:

```
MyClass val = GetAValue<MyClass>(myObject);
string strVal = GetAValue<string>(someObject);
```

For more information take a look at the [MSDN documentation on Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: You would need to return default(T) here as null would not work for value types - or place a Generic constraint on the method => where T : class

Comment: You can just return `default` without the `(T)` part, it automatically returns the default of method's return type.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like it would be done better inline.

What you can do is something like:

```
var requestedObject = someObject as TheTypeYouWant;
```

When you declare something like so, you will not get a null reference exception.  Then you can just do a simple

```
if(requestedObject != null){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use generics:

```
T foobar<T>() where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
void somefunc()
{
    Guid g = foobar<Guid>();
}
```

Comment: `foobar<T>() : where T new()` or you wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: also, this seems to meet the criteria as specified in the title, but not in the actual question. OP wants to return an input object cast to a new type.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the method like this:

```
protected TReturnType GetAValue<TReturnType>(Object someObject) where TReturnType : class
{
 if(someObject is TReturnType) return (TReturnType) someObject;
 return null;
}
```

Alternatively if you can't guarantee that TReturnType is a reference type you could leave off the generic constraint (TReturnType : class) and return default(TReturnType) instead of null - this would return the default type of TReturnType which would be 0 for an int...

Answer (score 1):

If you know the type at compile time (when writing the code) you can use generics.

If you only know the type at runtime (via Type), you can use the [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

Such conversion can be done using `as`

```
requestedObject as RequestedType
```

Wrapping this expression in a method does not really buy your anything

Answer (score 1):

I think you might actually be looking for a Convert.ChangeType mechanism.

```
private static object ChangeTypeTo<T>(this object value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return null;

    Type underlyingType = typeof (T);
    if (underlyingType == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

    if (underlyingType.IsGenericType && 
           underlyingType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof (Nullable<>)))
    {
        var converter = new NullableConverter(underlyingType);
        underlyingType = converter.UnderlyingType;
    }

    // Guid convert
    if (underlyingType == typeof (Guid))
    {
        return new Guid(value.ToString());
    }

    // Check for straight conversion or value.ToString conversion
    var objType = value.GetType();

    // If this is false, lets hope value.ToString can convert otherwise exception
    bool objTypeAssignable2typeT = underlyingType.IsAssignableFrom(objType);

    // Do conversion
    return objTypeAssignable2typeT ? Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType)
            : Convert.ChangeType(value.ToString(), underlyingType);
}
```