# Advice on calling method dynamically and returning corresponding type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, reflection, runtime

I have many DataObjects that all inherit from a particular class, and these DataObjects each have similar methods that make API calls.  I am trying to write an abstract method(s) that will allow me to accept input of API paths and request-method-types ("Get", "Put", "Post", etc.) to make the appropriate API call, and return an object of that type.

Note: I since I will be making API calls I will need to ensure async/await is possible.

This is non-working code describing what I'd like to do:

```
var dict = Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, Action>>
{
    //many key/value pairs of RequestMethodType/APIPath tuple keys 
    //and API calling method values
};

public T APICaller<T>(string requestMethodType, string path)
{
    //make tuple of rmt and path
    //use tuple to get API calling Action value from dictionary
    //invoke method and return object of correct type
}
```

I've done a lot of searching over the past few days, and here are some options I am trying/considering:

1. Use a Dictionary, Action> to map the input to the method.
   -issue with void lambda, struggling to return proper type
2. Use C# Generics to call API and return correct DataObject
   -Ran into issue where I couldn't return a dynamic type
3. Use reflection to make generic method in attempts to solve #2
4. Using dyanmic keyword to allow type to be determined at runtime

*I have also tried of mapping the RequestMethodType/Path tuples to a return type, then using the return type as the return type for a generic method making the API call.  When trying this I couldn't get past an error saying I was using a variable when a type was expected. (solve by using reflection??)

Here are some links for similar questions I have read:

[C# Is it possible to pass a type into a method and have the method return an object of that type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071681/c-sharp-is-it-possible-to-pass-a-type-into-a-method-and-have-the-method-return-a)

[How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

[generic class, how to set the type in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969681/generic-class-how-to-set-the-type-in-runtime)
-as well as many, many more.

EDIT (Adding code I have been working on):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GenericsTest2
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, Type> dict  = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, Type>()
        {
            {new Tuple<string, string> ("Get", "/path/to/api"), typeof(Car)}
        };

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string requestType = "Get";
            string path = "user/path";
            var objType = DetermineType (requestType, path);
            var obj = (Car)(object)GetObject (objType, path);
            Console.WriteLine (obj.Name);
        }

        public static Car CarMethod()
        {
            return new Car {Name = "John"};
        }
        public static Truck TruckMethod()
        {
            return new Truck {Id  = "ABC123"};
        }

        public static Type DetermineType(string requestMethodType, string path)
        {
            var tuple = Tuple.Create (requestMethodType, path);
            Type myData;
            dict.TryGetValue (tuple, out myData);
            return myData;
        }

        public static DataObject GetObject(Type t, string path)
        {
            //here I could use the path to call the actual API, but I'll just call 
            //CarMethod or TruckMethod to generate data for testing
            if(path == "user/path"){
                return CarMethod ();
            }else if (path == "settings/path"){
                return TruckMethod();
            }else{
                 throw new Exception ("something went wrong!");
            }
        }

        public class DataObject
        {
            public string Api { get; set; }
        }

        public class Car : DataObject
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class Truck : DataObject
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of the failed attempts with comments explaining what you would like to do and what does not work under which conditions?

Comment: @thehennyy, Thank you so much for reading.  Here is some code (added to end of original question).