# How do I return null from generic function?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have function like this:

```
private T DeserializeStream<T>(Stream data) where T : IExtensible
    {
        try
        {
            var returnObject = Serializer.Deserialize<T>(data);
            return returnObject;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.LoggerService.Log(this.AccountId, ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Everything is good, except that it complains about `return null;` part

> Cannot convert expression type 'null' to type 'T'

How do I return null from function like this?

Comment: You can return `default(T)` as answered in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302096/how-can-i-return-null-from-a-generic-method-in-c?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a generic constraint that `T` is a class (as structures are value types and cannot be `null`).

```
private T DeserializeStream<T>(Stream data) where T : class, IExtensible
```

As [@mindandmedia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218598/mindandmedia) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595777/how-do-i-return-null-from-generic-function/11595785#comment15346993_11595777), an alternative is to return the [`default` of `T`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/302096/1583) - this will allow it to work on value types (such a `Nullable<T>`, `int32` etc...).

Comment: I put this as an answer and it was converted to a comment...

Comment: @mindandmedia - You didn't mention the generic constraint. You put a single sentence and a link - that got converted to a comment. If you put in a bit more, it would have remained as an answer. Just pointing out what seems to have happened.

Comment: @Oded the order is class, IExtensible

Comment: it's ok, i still get sweet karma(?) from the comment... :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Probably got converted automatically. There are some heuristics for that which do not involve any mod.

Comment: @Oded Sounds plausible. A SO mod converting a post withing 3 minutes looked certainly strange.

Comment: @Oded this is how it should be where T : class, IExtensible the class comes first

Comment: @HatSoft - True. Was typing and my internal Syntax Error failed.