# C# pass through generic as parameter

Tags: c#, generics, pass-through

I have a method like that:

```
private Contact GetContactFromDbReaderWithSingleResult(DbDataReader dbReader)
{
    if (dbReader.HasRows)
    {
        return new DataReaderReflection().DataReaderToEntity<Contact>(dbReader)[0];
    }

    return null;
}
```

and then I could have a quite similar method like that:

```
private Email GetEmailFromDbReaderWithSingleResult(DbDataReader dbReader)
{
    if (dbReader.HasRows)
    {
        return new DataReaderReflection().DataReaderToEntity<Email>(dbReader)[0];
    }

    return null;
}
```

The signature of the DataReaderToEntity-Method is:

```
public List<T> DataReaderToEntity<T>(IDataReader dr) where T : new()
```

Now I want to create a generic variant `GetGenericEntityFromDbReaderWithSingleResullt`.

My approach looks like that, but it's not correct:

```
private object? GetEntityFromDbReaderWithSingleResult<T>(DbDataReader dbReader)
{
    if (dbReader.HasRows)
    {
        return new DataReaderReflection().DataReaderToEntity<typeof(T)>(dbReader)[0];
    }

    return null;
}
```

Still learning to deal with generics though...
What am I doing wrong?

Thank in advance!

Comment: It is `.DataReaderToEntity<T>()`

Comment: `DataReaderToEntity<typeof(T)>` should just be `DataReaderToEntity<T>`?

Comment: And the methods return-type should probably be just `T`, not `object?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your return type to T instead of object and remove the typeof:

```
private T GetEntityFromDbReaderWithSingleResult<T>(DbDataReader dbReader) where T : new()
{
    if (dbReader.HasRows)
    {
        return new DataReaderReflection().DataReaderToEntity<T>(dbReader)[0];
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere T might be a value type though which would not be nullable.

Comment: @HimBromBeere No you can't. Your code even would compile. You would get a message like **"Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead."** Have a look at [How can I return NULL from a generic method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302096/how-can-i-return-null-from-a-generic-method-in-c)

Comment: Tried that before, does not work, compiler says: 

'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'DataReaderReflection.DataReaderToEntity<T>(IDataReader)'

Comment: Your method needs to have  where T : new() as well. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I deleted my correction post after you changed your example. Thank you so much!