# Method that returns a nullable, generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
public T GetByID<T>(BaseAPI api)
{
    ....
    try
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        T returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
        return returnObject;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `return null` line throws an error, which I understand, because `T` is not nullable.  So, I'm trying to make `T` be nullable, and I'm not figuring it out.  No matter what I try, I get this:

> The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'

I'm trying various forms of this:

```
public T? GetByID<T>(BaseAPI api)
{
    ....
    try
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        T? returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T?>(responseString);
        return returnObject;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've seen a few other threads asking roughly the same question, but none of them have been specific enough to help me get all the way there. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302096/how-can-i-return-null-from-a-generic-method-in-c?rq=1) is REALLY close, but I'm not getting the answer to work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return NULL from a generic method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302096/how-can-i-return-null-from-a-generic-method-in-c)

Comment: what's wrong with using `default(T)` as in example linked provided by you ?

Comment: @Tigran, I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: @CaseyCrookston: so you mean `return default(T)` did not work for you like a solution or you got some compilation errors ?

Comment: Hmmm... good question.  It works now.  I must have had a typo?

Comment: Do not write catch-all exception handlers that don't even log anything. They'll give you endless grief as you try to figure out *why* your method didn't return anything, which could be anything from a network error to a JSON formatting error to even a `NullReferenceException`. If this is simplified from actual code, then OK, otherwise, at least add some logging, or a way to pass any error that happened to a handler you give to the function (`, Action<Exception> errorHandler = null) { ... errorHandler?.Invoke(ex)`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, yes, you are correct.  I just stripped the code in the OP of anything that didn't pertain to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the generic constraint  at the class level

`public class foo<T> where T : class`

`public T bar(){returns null;}` will now compile

## EDIT explaining why it works

When you use generics the compiler doesnt know what type it is. Since there are reference types and non reference types you cannot just return null. Because T needs to work for both reference types and non reference types.

By stating a constraint that T is a class you are stating it is a reference type and thus can return null.

### Edit

Per the comments the correct way would be

`default(T)`

I will copy past the reason why and link to the question

> Return default(T) which means you'll return null if T is a reference type (or a nullable value type), 0 for int, '\0' for char etc

[original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302096/how-can-i-return-null-from-a-generic-method-in-c)

Comment: wow, ok, that works. At least, it builds.  I'll test in a moment.  But, can you explain what this is doing?

Answer (score 1):

To return null should mark the T as class and return its default value:

```
public T GetByID<T>(BaseAPI api) where T: class
{
    ....
    try
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        T returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
        return returnObject;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```