# Handling No Content in ApiClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My ASP.NET Core 2.1 API app communicates with a third party API so I'm creating an ApiClient with generic CRUD methods in it.

The question is how I should handle a scenario where I got nothing from the API call -- I've seen cases where sometimes APIs return `204` but sometimes, they just return nothing at all with a status `200`.

When I try to return `null` in case my `response` has nothing in it, I'm getting an error that says I can't do it because `T` may not be `nullable`.

Here's my code:

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient

public MyClass(HttpClient httpClient)
{
   _httpClient = httpClient;
}

public Task<T> GetMyData<T>()
{
   try
   {
      var response = _httpClient.GetStringAsycn("https://someApiUrl");

      // This is where I'm a bit stuck
      if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
         return null; // <<-- Can't return NULL!

      var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
      return data;
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       throw new Exception(e.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: This article may help, try returning default(T) or restrict T to a reference type (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302096/how-can-i-return-null-from-a-generic-method-in-c)

Comment: Thank you! Both comments were useful and going with what @KirkLarkin suggested. If one of you posted your comment as answer, I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: You can do `Task.FromResult<T>(null)`.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment as I didn't see @RyanWilson's first. Perhaps it's a duplicate?

Comment: @Sam I think you should just vote to close this as the answer is well documented in the link I provided. Thank you for considering us with an accepted answer though.

Comment: @RyanWilson I just did :-) Thanks again!

Comment: @Sam Sure thing. Glad to help.