# How to write generic method for casting DBNull value to Nullable?

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have a database with a nullable column `foo_date`, where Npgsql maps the sql `NULL` value to an instance of the C# class `DBNull`. In my C# aggregate I use the type `DateTime?` for said column. So the question is how to easily convert `DBNull` to a nullable type.

I want to write a utility method like, e.g.,

```
public static class DbUtil
{
    public static T? CastToNullable<T>(object obj)
    {
        if (DBNull.Value.Equals(obj))
           return null;
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

which I would like to use like this:

```
IDataRecord rec = ...
DateTime? fooDate = DbUtil.CastToNullable<DateTime>(rec["foo_date"]);
```

However, I get the compiler error:

> Error  CS0403  Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead.

When I replace `return null` by `return default(T?)`, the compiler is happy, but the method does not return `null` but the default `Date`, i.e., `01.01.0001`.

What is the correct way to write the generic utility method above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return NULL from a generic method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302096/how-can-i-return-null-from-a-generic-method-in-c)

Comment: No, it doesn't. However, I found this: [Nullable type as a generic parameter possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209160/nullable-type-as-a-generic-parameter-possible) which is actually closer to my question, but produces a different compiler error: "CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'T?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".

Comment: but `default(DateTime?)` is null .. so change to `null` to `default(T)` replace `T?` with `T` and use like `DbUtil.CastToNullable<DateTime?>(...)`

Comment: You probably need `where T : struct`. Without that, `T?` just means "If `T` is a nullable reference type, then allow it to be null; otherwise, no effect". With the `struct` constraint, `T?` means `Nullable<T>`, which is what you want

Comment: canton7's Comment worked. Thanks! If you add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Does anybody know why I get said compiler error in  [Nullable type as a generic parameter possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209160/nullable-type-as-a-generic-parameter-possible), while other people seem to be fine with the accepted answer?

Comment: But... that's exactly what @Joelius' link says to do...

Comment: But the accepted answer from @Joelius' link describes something else and focuses on the reference case. Also, the type signature of the question's code example is different. Sorry if I didn't read in between the lines enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you've got nullable reference types enabled, otherwise that `T?` would be a compiler error.

`T?`, where `T` is a generic type parameter, has multiple meanings unfortunately.

- When `T` is a value type (i.e. you have a `where T : struct` constraint), `T?` means `Nullable<T>`.
- When `T` is a reference type (i.e. you have a `where T : class` constraint), `T?` means a reference type which is allowed to be null.
- When `T` is unconstrained, `T?` means "If `T` is a reference type, then this is allowed to be null; otherwise no effect".

In other words, if you have:

```
T? Foo<T>() => default;
```

If you call `Foo<int>()`, you get back an `int`, not an `int?`.

If however you have:

```
T? Foo<T>() where T : struct => default;
```

then `Foo<int>()` returns an `int?`.

In other words, your signature needs to be:

```
public static T? CastToNullable<T>(object obj) where T : struct
{
    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(obj))
       return null;
    return (T)obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check [Nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-5.0) structure which is in fact long/real version of `T?`

In that case your method would be

```
public static T? CastToNullable<T>(object obj) where T: struct
{
    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(obj))
       return null;
    return new Nullable<T>((T)obj);
}
```

That would work only for structures, for reference types you could add

```
public static T CastToNullableObj<T>(object obj) where T: class
{
    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(obj))
       return null;
    return (T)obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to access columns on your NpgsqlDataReader, but to get .NET null for null columns instead of `DBNull.Value`. If so, the usual way is to write use an extension method as follows:

```cs
public static class DbDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static T? GetValueOrDefault<T>(this DbDataReader reader, int ordinal)
        where T : class
        => reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : reader.GetFieldValue<T>(ordinal);
}
```

This can be used directly on your reader:

```cs
var s = reader.GetValueOrDefault<string>(0);
```